# what is wrong with my code of securing api with keycloak middleware?

Tags: keycloak

my application is in node and keycloak version is 23.0.1, and with keycloack.protect("seeker")
it is giving me 403 access denied error,

keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "myrealm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://entheo.info/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "mushgpt",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "wzIGQrl8R11Go4utvCRHIJlJPgaw83"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

keycloakConfig.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

let _keycloak;


function initKeycloak() {
    if (_keycloak) {
        console.warn("Trying to init Keycloak again!");
        return _keycloak;
    } 
    else {
        console.log("Initializing Keycloak...");
        var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
        _keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });
        return _keycloak;
    }
}

function getKeycloak() {
    if (!_keycloak){
        console.error('Keycloak has not been initialized. Please called init first.');
    } 
    return _keycloak;
}

module.exports = {
    initKeycloak,
    getKeycloak
};
```

index.js

```
const keycloak = require('./config/keycloak-config.js').initKeycloak();
app.use(keycloak.middleware());
```

router.js

```
const keycloak = require('../config/keycloak-config.js').getKeycloak();
router.get('/anonymous', function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello Anonymous");
});

router.get('/user',keycloak.protect('seeker'), function(req, res){
    
    res.send("Hello User");
});
```

and my token decoded :

```
"iat": 1708989507,
  "jti": "69c60121-76d2-49c1-bc1b-a948ac19bf4a",
  "iss": "http://iam.entheo.info/realms/myrealm",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "90ec5811-7e11-4367-a2dc-4bf829c23e3f",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "mushgpt",
  "session_state": "c4e91114-7a11-4bdd-a778-d81185eb8ea9",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "*"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "app-role",
      "seeker",
      "uma_authorization",
      "default-roles-entheo"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "mushgpt": {
      "roles": [
        "seeker"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "email profile",
  "sid": "c4f91114-7a11-4bdd-a778-d81185eb8ea9",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "Rev",
  "preferred_username": "aamir",
  "given_name": "aamir"
}
```

I rechecked the config, on keycloack admin console, added role ad realm access, client access and checked with keycloack.protect("realm:seeker") and also with keycloack.protect("mushgpt:seeker") but error still persists, please check the code and let me know where I am wrong

Comment: What does the response from Keycloak say?  It's likely more than just a 403.

Comment: @stdunbar it says access denied and status is 403